# Prolog Findall repeticion de valores

Tags: lista, prolog, lógica

Estoy trabajando con Prolog y tengo la siguiente base de conocimiento:

```
ransomware(1,grandcrab,porcentaje(78.5),fechaDeAparicion([10,01,2020]),campana([enero, febrero, marzo, abril])).
ransomware(2,babuk, porcentaje(7.61),fechaDeAparicion([05,07,2020]),campana([julio,agosto])).
ransomware(3,cerber,porcentaje(7.61),fechaDeAparicion([20,01,2020]),campana([enero,febrero,diciembre])).
ransomware(4,matsnu,porcentaje(2.63),fechaDeAparicion([03,04,2020]),campana([abril,octubre])).
ransomware(5,wannacry,porcentaje(2.41),fechaDeAparicion([29,06,2020]),campana([julio,septiembre])).
ransomware(6,congur,porcentaje(1.52),fechaDeAparicion([05,07,2020]),campana([julio])).
ransomware(7,locky,porcentaje(1.29),fechaDeAparicion([12,05,2020]),campana([mayo,diciembre])).
ransomware(8,teslacrypt,porcentaje(1.12),fechaDeAparicion([04,11,2020]),campana([noviembre,diciembre])).
ransomware(9,rkor,porcentaje(1.11),fechaDeAparicion([10,03,2020]),campana([marzo,mayo])).
ransomware(10,reveton,porcentaje(0.70),fechaDeAparicion([29,08,2020]),campana([agosto])).
```

De allí quiero hacer una regla que junte en una lista los nombres de los ransomware que tienen campaña en enero y los que tienen en diciembre; para eso hice esta regla:

```
listarRansomwareEnyDic(Lista):-
    findall(Nombre,
          (ransomware(_,Nombre,_,_,campana(Meses)),(esMiembro(diciembre,Meses);esMiembro(enero,Meses))),
           Lista).
```

Mi problema es que se repite para aquellos valores que aparecen en enero y diciembre.
¿Alguien sabe como evitar esa repetición?
Desde ya, gracias.

aclaración: la función esMiembro verifica que se encuentre el mes dentro de la lista.

```
esMiembro(X,[X|_]).
esMiembro(X,[_|Y]) :- esMiembro(X,Y).
```